# How to return number-loops in String? [Java]

Tags: java, string, return, nested-loops

I am practicing some exercises of java and I got some problems in returning this in String as asked in the question.

> "Write nested for-loops to produce the following output from the given
>   input n."

Can someone help me to return this same logic in String? [Java]

```
public String numberLoops(int n) {
    int n = 8;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j < n - i) {
                System.out.print(".");
            } else if (j == j) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }

        }
        if (i < n) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you give more details of the question? And i think System.out.print("") will do nothing.

Comment: `StringBuilder` and Google are your friends.

Comment: And what is the output supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

you can use object stringbuider to append the output

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Won't just give you the finished code because, well, what fun would that be?  But here are some hints.

Basically what you want to do is collect your results in a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instance instead of printing them, and then obtain the final `String` result from the `StringBuilder`.  If `sb` is your `StringBuilder` instance, you can map your I/O operations to `StringBuilder` operations roughly as follows:

`System.out.print(x)` => `sb.append(x)`

`System.out.println(x)` => `sb.append(x).append('\n')`

`System.out.println()` => `sb.append('\n')`

When you're done, `sb.toString()` will give you the `String` version of the result you've constructed in `sb`.